# Find a formula of sequence: $\frac{-1}{2}, 0, \frac{1}{10}, 0, \frac{-1}{26}, 0, \frac{1}{50}, 0, \frac{-1}{82}, 0, \frac{1}{122}, 0, \dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I'm working on a discrete math homework that finding a formula for the following sequence:

$$\frac{-1}{2}, 0, \frac{1}{10}, 0, \frac{-1}{26}, 0, \frac{1}{50}, 0, \frac{-1}{82}, 0, \frac{1}{122}, 0, \dots$$

I've tried but can't find the same difference between those numbers.

I come up with something as: $\frac{1}{2}((-1)^{(x-1)}-1)\times0.5\times0.2$
But it's not anywhere close as I mentioned, I don't know the difference.

Also, is there way to apply to find formula for this kind of problem.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Every non-zero element is followed by $0$ except $1/10$

Comment: Should there be a zero between $\frac{1}{10}$ and $\frac{-1}{26}$ ?

Comment: @MartinHansen yeah, I just edited it!!!

Comment: The unsigned reciprocals of the non-zero elements appears to be the "centered square numbers", sequence [A069894](https://oeis.org/A069894) at the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. $a(n) = 4n^2 + 4n + 2$

Comment: Alternating signs are easily dealt with by $(-1)^n.$ But you have a pattern of signs that repeats every four numbers. Can you use complex numbers, that is, $i^n$?

Comment: You can always use the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C+10%2C+26%2C+50%2C+82&sort=&language=english&go=Search), though I suppose that doesn't help on an exam.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Consider the sequence
\begin{eqnarray*}
2(n^2+(n+1)^2).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any method to find that formula?

Comment: Finite differences of the denominators would work. I just noticed that these values are $2$ times the sum of consecutive squares.

Comment: You could also say $k^2 + 1$ for odd $k.$

Comment: $2(n^2+(n+1)^2) = 4n^2 + 4n + 2 = (2n + 1)^2 + 1.$